# How do you disable a select tag upon choosing in a rails web app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html-select, erb

I would like to present a select menu and, when the user chooses an option, **disable** that menu (preserving the selection).

My code is as follows:

my_controller.rb:

```
def action 
    @menu_disabled = true
end
```

my_helper.rb:

```
def menu_tag
   select_tag :menu_name,
           options_from_collection_for_select(@menu_options, 'id', 'title'),
           :prompt => 'my prompt',
           :disabled => @ menu_disabled
end
```

_menu.erb:

```
<%= menu_tag %>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<!-- headers, description, etc -->
<%= render :partial => 'menu' %>
<!-- footers, etc, -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu_name').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= action_path %>",
        data: {
          selection_id : $('#menu_name').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });

    });
  });
</script>
```

action.js.erb:

```
$('#menu_name').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'menu') %>");
```

This doesn't work. The menu remains functional, and displays the prompt upon selection. Other changes (for example, modifying the `@menu_options` collection in `action`) are displayed correctly. What's happening?

Rails version: 4.0.2

Ruby version: 2.0.0

Jquery-rails gem version: 3.1.2

Browser: Safari 8.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replaceWith` instead of `html` since you want to replace the whole `select` element.